# Choosing a Model for Storing Complex Dynamic User Profiles/Settings

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, web-applications, asp.net-membership, asp.net-profiles

Here's the **layout**:

- I'm developing an internal ASP.NET Web App (in VB.NET) with an SQL Server Database.
- Since my users are strictly internal, I'm using the "Windows" method for automatic authentication.
- I have four user Roles, each with their own very unique, and dynamic, set of settings.
- *BONUS: Each user may have multiple Roles and hence multiple Profiles.*

From my extensive research I have determined the following **two methods** for storing user profile settings (both of which prompting the question "HOW?"), though I'm not sure **which is best** (if any):

- Store profiles and associated settings in the DB (Using what structure? From preliminary mapping, I've created at least four tables which is starting to get grossly unmanageable and unmaintainable)
- Use the **built-in ASP.NET Membership & Profile object**? (I can't seem to find a good tutorial on this. Does this method still require DB support? Again, using what table structure?) -*I'm most interested in this possible solution*

Example:

My most complex user group requires the ability to store a profile of all (user-selected) products associated with the user. Say I'm a product manager and I want my account to show me all the products that I've selected for which I am responsible. Obviously each member of my role would have different products and a different quantity of them, etc. **Perhaps** user page settings (e.g. search, sortation, order defaults, etc) could be stored in a generic table, with a reference to an auxillary settings table for the weird stuff which can be linked to through a special record which could act as a "foreign key" of sorts.

As Requested, **one** of my ideas for a table plan:

```
    Users (ID, Username, RoleID)
    Roles (ID, RoleName, Description) --Lookup Table
    Settings (ID, Name, Value)
    UserSettings (ID, UserID, SettingID) --Junction Table
```

Then the questions arise:

1. When should I use a row vs a column?
2. If I use a column per setting I can define datatypes, but column count could get out of control. On the other hand if I use a row per setting it makes much better sense, but I lose control over the data type for the setting.
3. Should I omit the UserSettings table and just append a name=value pair record for each setting in the Settings table with a UserID foreign key instead?
4. etc etc...

My Ideal Answer:

As you can see I have many questions and have found seemingly little help. I would **LOVE** it if someone could break it down for me in **simple terms**. Please tell me your professional recommendations and some super simple tips on how to implement it (i.e. which ASP.NET **objects** to use, as well as how said objects provide the **mechanism** for managing my complex profiles)

Comment: It sounds like you may be looking at things askew.  Would it make more sense for each product to have a unique owner rather than a user having a list of products?  If the relationship is many-to-many then you'll need a table to handle the mapping.  Don't fear, tables are your friends.

Comment: The question seems very broad. Can you describe the four tables you envisioned in your first bullet?

Comment: @Aaron: I'd rather have fresh ideas than to regurgitate my mess. I'm most interested in the built-in ASP.NET functionality as it's new to me and I've found very little helpful documentation on its implementation. Thanks :) ... and user92546: It is indeed many-to-many.

Comment: My question was based on this: For anyone (or at least for me) to bring any fresh ideas, I need to have *some* understanding of the basic requirements. You are talking about roles and products but it is very abstract to me. Like @Cade I would lean toward modeling this in the database, not in ASP.NET, but I can't really offer anything except for a generic stance unless I have a slightly lower-level idea of what we're actually talking about. Can you at least *name* the four tables you arrived at?

Comment: @Aaron: Added as requested. I look forward to your thoughts and appreciate your willingness to help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this almost certainly needs to be modeled in the database.

The products associated with a user would not really be a role-based thing - so would have to be largely independent of the role even though you say only managers would have that relationship.  Only users in a role would have that linkage, but that's kind of a high-level restriction you might enforce at the application level or some higher level constraint - not with a foreign key - unless you had a linkage which depended upon user and role.

Then a user acting as manager might have certain products, but acting as a salesman, different products.  Then the role would be in the link table as well.  Sometimes link table rows do have attributes about the linkage, not just the linkage themselves (usually things like effective dates and active/disabled flags).